# Fontello and ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, fontello

I am trying to use Fontello icons. To do this I need to set the innerHTML to be `&#xe821;`. However the `&` keeps getting escaped and I dont want to use set html dangerously. Is there anyway to use this?

It says I can also use `0xe821` but I couldn't figure out how.

My code:

```
React.createClass({
render: function() {
   return React.createElement('div', {}, '&#xe821;');
}});
```

Comment: How about `'\ue831'`?

Comment: You could create a CSS class and use the character code as its `content` property! The you can simply set that as the class for the div.

Comment: Holy heck that worked @zerkms thank you!!!! May you please post to solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `'\ue831'` instead. It defines a character directly in a string literal, so React does not need and will not escape it.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi zerkms I was having trouble converting the times symbol to unicode. Docs say it is `× multiplication sign 0327 215 0xD7 &times;` however doing `\ue215` `\ueD7` `\ue327` are all giving me malformed unicode character escape sequence.

Comment: @Noitidart http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d7/index.htm Check the `C/C++/Java source code` section